# Insert element in specific position in matrix C++ programming

Tags: c++, matrix

I am currently doing Matric in C++, I want to create a matrix that can store non_zero_elements. What I want to do is to insert an element in specific position and further print it out the matrix with non_zero_element and zero_element. This is my initialised matrix :

```
int A[4][4] =
{
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
};
```

Below are my codes

```
void SM::readElement(int row, int column, int value)
{
    m = row;
    n = column;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << "\t\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == row && j == column)
            {           
                A[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

void  SM::printMatrix()
{

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << A[i][j];
    }
}
```

The driver :

```
    int main()
    {
        SM sm;

        int choice, column, row, value;

        do {
            sm.Menu();
            cin >> choice;
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                do
                {
                    cout << "Enter row -> ";
                    cin >> row;
                } while (row < 0 || row >= 11);

                do
                {
                    cout << "Enter column -> ";
                    cin >> column;
                } while (column < 0 || column >= 11);

                do {
                    cout << "Enter value -> ";
                    cin >> value;
                } while (value <= 0);

                sm.readElement(row, column, value);

}
```

I want to read the elements and insert it into specific row and column and print out a whole matrix with updated matrix after inserting the element. I need somebody point out the errors. Thank you very much.

```
Input row = 2
Input column = 2
Input value = 5
```

Real Output :

```
int A [4][4] = 
{
{ 5 , 5 , 0 , 0 },
{ 5 , 5 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
};
```

Expected Output :

```
int A [4][4] = 
{
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 5 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
};
```

And I found that my codes will not accept row/column =0, it only starting with row/column >= 1.

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just `A[row][column] = value;`

Comment: If the array is global, `int A[4][4];` will initialize it to all zero. If it's local to a function, you should use an explicit initialization list.

Comment: Why are you `insert`ing a value in a `read` function?

Comment: Do you really have to create your own?  There are many matrix libraries out there free to use.

Comment: Because I want to read the user input with triplet which meant user will input row, column and the element that want to insert.

Comment: I couldn't find any sources which can insert a value into a matrix with specific position, that's why I create it with my own.

Comment: I think the loop you made to set the value is absolutely hilarious. +1 lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int A[4][4] =
{
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
};
```

is the correct syntax for declaring and initializing a 2d array. You should probably be using vectors though.

Comment: ok, I will initialise matrix like this, but then how should I input an element with a specific position into this matrix?

Comment: You can just access it with the index as you would with any array: A[0][0] = 1

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert an element, say **int** value, into position [row,column] of a matrix A it suffices to do

```
A[row][column] = value;
```

In order to print the new matrix just call the function printMatrix() you wrote after the insertion

Comment: If I just use the statement u stated above, let's say I input row=2, column=2 and value=9, it will fill up all 2*2 to 9, but what I want is just insert value 9 to A[2][2]

Comment: @Anthony You have to initialize matrix A first and then follow the steps from the statement on order to work. The initialization can be done just like you did it above

Comment: I did initialised matrix A and it can replace the element, but the problem is I can't just replace only 1 element instead of replace all 2*2 in matrix A

Comment: @Anthony can you be more specific? What so you mean all 2*2?. It will replace the element A[2][2] with the integer value 9

Comment: I had updated my question, please take a look, thank you.